# How to draw dotted circle in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, logo, shapes, designers

I am pretty new to graphic design world & obviously Inkscape too. I just need to draw a simple circle with dots in Inkscape. I have tried all the options in the stroke style section, but wasn't successful. I have searched online about this, but found only a workable solution [here](http://goinkscape.com/how-to-design-a-circular-logo-in-inkscape/). But I think that is complicated solution to do just this simple job. Is there any other easier way to draw a simple circle with dots? I really hope there is something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, three possible solutions in one video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WU-8k05WDwI

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I have requested the channel owner for a tutorial on this topic and she honored my request. I am really grateful to her, now my problem has been solved. :)

Comment: So you are the cause for the video. <g>

Answer (score 9):

You could use a pattern along a path effect.

Here's an example. The pattern itself was simply a small circle (shown top left), which was copied to the clip board, then applied as a pattern to a larger circle:

[image]

More info about pattern along a path functionality [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html)

Comment: Could you please describe the steps more briefly? I am quiet new to design & Inkscape. So it would be really great if you do that. :)

Comment: @tuxtu GDSE isn't really a tutorial on demand site. I have included a link at the bottom of my answer so you can find out more about the pattern along a path functionality, and also you can look up tutorials by searching that term.

Comment: +1 for "Could you please describe the steps more briefly?" - what you've done here is subject to linkrot and adds an additional hurdle to actually accomplishing the task asked in the question.

Comment: @AdamWilliams - the link was provided only for more information on functionality from an online Inkscape user manual, **not** for how to accomplish the task which is already explained in the answer.  Note also that GDSE is not a tutorial on demand website. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the link you've provided uses an unnecessarily complex method. The project you seek is called polar array in some CAD software. Using "inkscape polar array" provided many results, one of which is the SEGD resource:

[How to create these rotated clones?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26679/how-to-create-these-rotated-clones)

In the linked answer, the responder used large circles as his object, but you can use anything created in Inkscape. It's an easy matter to resize his hula hoops to dots.

[image: link image]

The image above is from the linked answer.

Answer (score 2):

I will propose another solution.

1. You can start with a circle and add a marker to the stroke.

   [image]
2. Convert to stroke. Path→Object to Path or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>`.
3. Select all the nodes on the stroke and add new nodes with: `Insert new nodes into selected segments`. Do this until you have the number of points that you want.
4. Convert stroke to path. Path→Stroke to path or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>`.
5. Ungroup and delete the line.

[image]

Comment: This is the same method used in the tutorial which the OP already linked to. However the OP wants other methods.

Comment: @BillyKerr, sorry. I will delete the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy/paste "⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤" as text, select it and your circle (which should be a path), and use *Text* > *Put on Path*.

[image: Big blue dots]

Boom! No complicated steps, no changing your circle, no distorted dots (which is [what "Pattern along Path" gives you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zckwH.png), especially when you have large dots).

Plus it works well no matter the shape you're putting the dots on.

Answer (score 0):

More options:

- use a stroke with a dot pattern (requires the correct ratio between the dash length and the stroke width, and also requires rounded caps): https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/wlLrh
- use the polar arrangement option of the Object > Arrange dialog: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=31762